# Grails android-gcm plugin installation

Tags: android, grails, google-cloud-messaging

How to install android-gcm osoco plugin in grails ?

I tried using **grails install android-gcm** but I got an error **plugin not found**!
How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

The Grails `install-plugin` is no longer used. Instead you now install plugins through your `grails-app/conf/Buildconfig.groovy`.

For this plugin you need to add two things. First the custom repository in the repository section of your `Buildconfig.groovy`:

```
repositories {
  ...
  mavenRepo "https://github.com/slorber/gcm-server-repository/raw/master/releases/"
  ...
}
```

Next, you need to add the actual plugin to your plugins section of your `BuildConfig.groovy`:

```
plugins {
  ...
  compile ":android-gcm:0.2"
  ...
}
```

Comment: Hey I made these changes too but i am getting the following error:

:: #android-gcm;0.2: not found

Comment: I was using the information on the plugin page. Have you tried `:android-gcm:1.0.2` instead? I can't try right now, traveling. Looking at the repo that might work.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot. I think it was a version issue. We moved our project to the latest version. Now its working ! :)

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out.

Answer (score 0):

In Grails 3.x I had to use this:
(in build.gradle)

**Add repo:**

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    ...
    maven { url "https://github.com/slorber/gcm-server-repository/raw/master/releases"}
}
```

**Add dependency**

```
dependencies {
    ...    

    compile "com.google.android.gcm:gcm-server:1.0.2"

    ...
}
```